# How to connect Visual Studio 2019 to TFS server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

I have TFS 2018.  I'm trying to connect visual studio 2019.  I can already use tfs via web browser.  I can log in and everything is fine.  But when I try to connect through vs, I can't get authorized.  I get

Server 'https://Myserver:8080/tfs' was not added.  TF30063. You are not authorized to access https://myserver:8080/tfs

I researched the error code and tried all the fixes including deleting the windows credentials, running vs as admin and others.  Like I said, I can log in via my web browser with no problem.

When I try to connect to project, It has my Microsoft account.  I enter the above url and I'm prompted for my windows login (same for the browser) and I keep getting the error.  I thought maybe I add the account before connecting, but when I try to add an account, the only popup wants me to use a Microsoft account or GitHub account.  I can't add my Windows account.

So how do I connect my visual studio to my tfs server?

Thank you.

Comment: How's the URL like when you login from web portal? Is it `http` or `https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not get a Microsoft Account Prompt if you are trying to connect locally.  The prompt is to validate your instance of VS towards your MSDN subscription.  You would need to "login" with you Microsoft or Azure AD user that can validate your VS license and to be able to synchronize your settings from one VS to another.  This login is the one here

[image]

Notice the account settings there, if you click on this you can also add your Visual Studio 2019 Static Key and then you don't need to login every month unless you want to sync your settings.

Bottom line, when connecting to TFS 2018 it will not ask you for Microsoft Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you use the correct URL, and use `http` instead of `https`. Also, try the following items:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances, delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService.
2. Clear TFS caches %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache
3. Click `Add Azure DevOps Server` and add the server URL:

   [image]